# How to generate single number output for multiple pattern types in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dictionary

I'm using R to work on a project where I've measured the calcium volume on the aortic valve. I have 5 columns: Volume on the three leaflets and total volume inside/outside. To characterize the various distributions I find in my patients, I want to associate each pattern (12 total) with a single number in a new column. For example:

- Volume Leaflet 1 > Volume Leaflet 2 > Volume Leaflet 3 and Volume Inside > Outside --> 1
- Volume Leaflet 1 > Volume Leaflet 2 > Volume Leaflet 3 and Volume Outside > Inside --> 2
- Volume Leaflet 2 > Volume Leaflet 1 > Volume Leaflet 3 and Volume Inside > Outside --> 3

...

- Volume Leaflet 3 > Volume Leaflet 2 > Volume Leaflet 1 and Volume Outside > Inside --> 12

I looked into dictionaries in R, but haven't found a good solution.

```r
structure(
  list(ctanalysis_abscv_l = c(7.897880437, 1263.82504529, 80.64252297, 602.51047473),
       ctanalysis_abscv_r = c(15.38538081, 842.835871, 94.030160661, 694.35817674),
       ctanalysis_abscv_n = c(275.901870908, 1356.2005494, 358.2288726, 794.49459655),
       ctanalysis_inside_volume = c(35.8760545, NA, 153.5488922, 715.0530575),
       ctanalysis_outside_volume = c(264.2563071, NA, 379.5414025, 1381.3362945)),
  row.names = c(NA, 4L),
  class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Added a dput output from my data frame, hope that helps akrun!

Comment: thanks can you sshow your expected output for that 4 rows

Comment: Ya so I have absolute volumes in my data frame, but generated a generalized pattern to characterize the data more easily. I have 12 total patterns as I mentioned above and each patient should be slotted into one of those 12.
So patient 1: Left = 7.89788, Right = 15.3853, Non = 275.9019, Inside Volume = 35.87605, Outside Volume = 264.2563. 
I want to somehow code: Non > R > L and Outside > Inside. Using the pattern above, this would be pattern 7 let's say. I would want the output "7" in a new column. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: that is fine, just wanted to know the expected based on your input

Comment: Edited to be more clear

Comment: for the missing values in row2, which group it belongs as it is missiing in both iinside and outside

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tough without the data frame provided, BUT, I imagine you could assign the new values to a vector then bind them in a data frame. it would look like:

```
test.dat = ## whatever your original findings are
new.num = ## the vector of the number for each column. (need 5)
new.dat = data.frame(test.dat, new.num) ## new frame with "Test.dat$Findings"
```

I Hope this is useful. If it's not exactly what you're asking I'm sorry. I'm all about helping in the med field.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to convert to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` then `arrange` the 'value' column, do a group by 'rn' to `paste` the column names and create an index with `match`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -rn, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
    arrange(rn, desc(value)) %>% 
    group_by(rn) %>%
    summarise(name = str_c(name, collapse="|")) %>% 
    mutate(new = match(name, unique(name))) %>% 
    select(-rn, -name) %>%
    bind_cols(df1, .)
```